# What is meaning of ACTIVE in ASP.NET(ACTIVE Server Pages)?

Tags: asp.net

What is meaning of **ACTIVE** in ASP.NET(**ACTIVE** Server Pages)?

Can you please provide an explanation on why it is named '**ACTIVE**'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active was one of Microsoft's favorite words when the original ASP first came out. Other items like ActiveDirectory, ActiveSync, and ActiveX Data Objects also came out of this mid-late 90's "Active" era.

It had more to do with marketing than anything IMO.

EDIT: And ActiveX and Active Accessibility...

Comment: +1 for marketing. It could just as well have been any buzz work like "Dynamic" or "Visual".

Answer (score 2):

This is referring to the fact that the pages are running ActiveX scripts and server controls, from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972347.aspx):

> Microsoft® Active Server Pages (ASP)
>   is the server-side execution
>   environment in Microsoft Internet
>   Information Server (IIS) 3.0 that
>   enables you to run ActiveX™ scripts
>   and ActiveX server components on the
>   server. By combining scripts and
>   components, developers can create
>   dynamic content and powerful Web-based
>   applications easily.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to you are Actively Running Scripts.

> Developing functionality in ASP websites  is enabled by the active scripting engine's support of the Component Object Model (COM), with each object providing a related group of frequently-used functions and data attributes.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages).

Answer (score 1):

This is purely my opinion (and not necessarily the fact) but I would assume because unlike an HTML page it's not static. It's just another word for Dynamic.

Edit: David's post offers a better actual description of it.

Answer (score 1):

i think it might have to do with ActiveX ... see here -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Scripting

Answer (score 1):

An active web document consists of a computer program(JS,applet etc.) that the server sends to the browser and that the browser must run locally. • When it runs, the active document program can interact with the user and change the display continuously.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the pages have behavior... that they *act* to generate the result the user sees, rather than simply being a copy of the document the user ends up seeing.